# OWASP Top Ten static analysis for Typescript / Angular 2

Tags: security, typescript, static-analysis, owasp

Do Somebody know if there are OWASP Rules implementation for Typescript (or Angular 2)?

I found out some references about static analysis for Typescript code, but none of them implements the OWASP Rules Top Ten attacks.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a list of analysis tools here: https://owasp.org/www-community/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools But the only one explicitly mentioning Angular is [HCL](https://www.hcltechsw.com/appscan/offerings/source) which is commercial (30 days trial).